# react js trigger function from any other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that basically loads a video in an overlay using JW Player (simplified example below).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactJWPlayer from 'react-jw-player'

class VideoPopup extends Component {

render() {
    return (            
        <div id="video">
            <ReactJWPlayer 
              playerId='video-player'
              playerScript='https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/vr6ybmGf.js'
              file='path to video file'
            />
        </div>

    )
  }
}

export default VideoPopup;
```

I would like the component to sit directly in the root of my app, but I need to be able to display it when called from ANY other component - this might be a child component, a child of a child, a sibling etc. etc. I was hoping to be able to call it and pass the video file reference simply like below:

```
<button onClick={somehow show video popup}>show video popup</button>
```

I understand how to do this easily if there is a direct parent-child relationship, but not if I want to place the link in a variety of different components; I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You can achieve this with [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html).

Comment: Thanks @Andrew - seems it will be worth my time to get my head around Redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this

- You can define a function that controls the  show/hide functionality
  of the video player in the app component itself and pass it down as a
  prop to all the components where the event can be fired.
- Use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/). This is the ideal choice. You just have to dispatch an action from anywhere in your app and the corresponding reducer will take care of the functionality.
- Using a global function (not recommended).

Please comment if you need more explanation.

Comment: how would I perform the first one - will it work even if the event is fired multiple components deep?

Comment: Yes. You just need to keep passing the function down as prop. You can keep pasing function as deep you want.     For example :  suppose you have your handler defined in root. Then nested components can call it as shown. (Suppose "component" has an embedded element "component1child")
   <component1 handler=this.handler/> then in <component1child   handler=this.props.handler ></component1child> just keep passing how many levels you want to pass down.

Comment: that works great! thanks Amit. In the future I will implement Redux, but for right now this helps me achieve what I am after.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get rid of the parent-children relationships when it comes to actions, use an event manager like Redux ([react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)). It is pretty standard an becomes necessary as your app grows anyway.

The principle is that wherever you place your link, it will fire an "action" on click, which is sent to a global dispatcher that other components listen to for changes.

Comment: Thanks @JulienD - I thought this might be the case. I was hoping for a quick sticky-tape solution for now but it seems I should just dive in and get my head around Redux

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make global function and call it wherever you want.

```
showVideoPopup () {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <VideoPopup />,
        document.getElementById('popupHolder')
    );
}
```