# React change login link to logout after login

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a  website in react where my header and login form are different component .I want after login my login link in header change to logout.

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: When props and state become cumbersome, you need an event manager. Look at answers there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46139140/react-js-trigger-function-from-any-other-component.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html You can have a separate login and logout component or alter the login component to render something different on login.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently done something similar.

An easy solution would be to use sessionStorage and redux.

You need to store the jwt token in sessionStorage and check its existance everytime it renders (example through onComponentWillMount). If logged in, dispatch an action to update a "logged_in" state. The Header component will render according to the logged_in state.

My Header Component looks something like this:

```
class Header extends React.Component {  
  componentWillMount() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('jwt'))
      this.props.loginSuccess();
  }

  render() {
    console.log("logged_in: ", this.props.logged_in);

    if (this.props.logged_in) {
      return (
        <nav>
          <NavLink to="/" 
            activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
          {" | "}
          <Link to="/products" activeClassName="active">Products</Link>
          {" | "}
          <a href="/logout">log out</a>
        </nav>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <nav>
          <NavLink to="/" 
            activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
          {" | "}
          <Link to="/login" activeClassName="active">
            log in</Link>
        </nav>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: With componentWillMount header menu is change only when after login we refresh the page but we don't want to refresh the page

Comment: Yes and No! Any component in ReactJS is automatically rerendered if a state that it controls changes. That's the whole idea of React! So I would also put a reducer called `this.props.isLoggedin` that causes the Header to rerender.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global EventEmitter

https://github.com/facebook/emitter

Create file 'golbal_emitter.js' with code:

`module.exports = new EventEmitter();`

Then in your component:

Header(in componentDidMount): 

`var emitter = require 'global_emitter';
emitter.addListener('afterLogin', function() {});`

In login component(after success login):

`var emitter = require 'global_emitter';
emitter.emit('afterLogin');`